# differential equation forms vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

show that the set of solutions of the homogeneous linear differential equation $$y'+p(x)y=0$$ on an interval $I=[a,b]$ forms a vector subspace $W$ of the real vector space of continous functions on $I$. what is the dimension of $W$?

my try:
$$\frac {dy}{dx} + p(x)y= 0$$
on solving this , we get
$$y= ce^{-\int p(x) dx}$$

for subspace: 
$$y_1= c_1e^{-\int p(x) dx}\\y_2= c_2e^{-\int p(x) dx}$$
let $h,k$ be scalar multiples in $I$  ..so,
$$(hy_1+ky_2)(x)= (hy_1)(x)+(ky_2)(x) = h(y_1(x))+k(y_2(x))$$

is this way correct ?? and how to find dimension?

Comment: You don't need to solve the equation to show that $W$ is subspace. The solution you have above shows that the dimension is one.

Comment: What are $x1$ and $x2$?

Comment: You need more than continuity to talk about differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the space of *differentiable* functions on $I$.

Consider $T: V \to V$ given by $T(f) = f' + pf$.

Then $T$ is a linear operator on $V$ and $W = \ker T$.

This proves that $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

The solution of a first-order linear differential equation $f' + pf=0$ is determined by the initial condition $f(a)$. Therefore, $W$ has dimension $1$.